# OpenCover coverage glitch?

Tags: c#, .net, opencover

I updated OpenCover version in the project and got the follwoing:

[image]

How is this possible if the line #77 is covered? I understand that the code itself is not briliant but I am fine with a possible exception on that line #76. I have also another one unexpected behavior:

[image]

But the thing is that I have a test to check the exception. Could anybody help to understand what is not covered?